# Mysql_query won't copy id into another row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a INSERT query to copy the value of id into another row called `sortingId`, which works fine.

It works too when I try to copy id, into sortingId directly in phpmyadmin.

But combined in the following code, it dosen't work. No errors, but sortingId is just 0.

And if I change `$sql2` to "asdjh" it doesn't get and error, so it seem like the second `mysql_query` is just ignored and never executed

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO items (name) VALUES (\'TEC TEST !"#!12\');";
$sql2 = "SELECT @last_id := MAX(id) FROM items; UPDATE items SET sortingId = id WHERE id = @last_id;";

$sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql1);
$sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql2);

if (mysqli_insert_id($this->db) > 0) {
    $this->response($this->json(array( 'inserted_id' => mysqli_insert_id($this->db))), 200);
}
```

**UPDATE - with the big help from tadman:**

Had to separate the mysqli queries by removing the ";" and make a query for each line:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO items (name) VALUES (\'TEC TEST !"#!12\')";
$sql2 = "SELECT @last_id := MAX(id) FROM items";
$sql3 = "UPDATE items SET sortingId = id WHERE id = @last_id";

$sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql1);

if(mysqli_insert_id($this->db) > 0){
    $responsedId = mysqli_insert_id($this->db);
    $sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql2);
    $sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql3);      
    $this->response($this->json(array( 'inserted_id' => $responsedId)), 200);
}
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: You can't run more than one query per `query` call. Split that up into two separate operations.

Comment: A lot of problems can be detected and resolved by [enabling exceptions in `mysqli`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) so mistakes aren't easily ignored.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @tadman for all your detailed answers!... I´m new to mysqli and the code i´m trying to modify here is from a tutorial on rest APIs... So you say my problem is that I have two calls on one query? Isn't my code two separate query calls? one with $sql1 and one with $sql2? I can't see how I'm going to make this work. I tried with changing the last $sql to $sqlSecound

Comment: The `;` separator is only meaningful to MySQL clients to indicate "end of statement", not low-level drivers like `mysqli` where it's pointless and should be omitted. It's three statements, two of which are jammed into the same string. You'll need to break that out into two separate, self-contained queries.

Comment: Yes!!! great, thank you so much! Can you make it as an answer, so I can mark it as solved? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have an escaping/quoting problem in the first example that can be fixed:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO items (name) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", "TEC TEST !\"#!12");
$stmt->execute();
```

The `bind_param` function makes it very easy to insert arbitrary data without having to fuss over escaping issues, and as a bonus makes it reliably safe to insert user-supplied data as well without the risk of SQL injections.

The biggest problem here is trying to force two queries into a single `query` call:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT @last_id := MAX(id) FROM items; UPDATE items SET sortingId = id WHERE id = @last_id;";

$sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql2);
```

Where the `;` separator is only used by interactive clients like the `mysql` command-line tool or popular front-ends. The `mysqli` driver doesn't do this for you, instead you need to split it up:

```
$res1 = $this->db->query("SELECT @last_id := MAX(id) FROM items");
$res2 = $this->db->query("UPDATE items SET sortingId = id WHERE id = @last_id");
```

Where there I've applied some of the advice I've given about how to use `mysqli` more effectively as well.

One final thing to note here is that [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) tends to be a lot more pleasant to use, so if you're just getting started consider that approach as well. It's not MySQL specific, so if you ever use another database back-end your time spent learning it won't be wasted.